# Chrome extension DOM Manipulation doesn't work all the time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to learn javascript while also messing around with building a chrome extension. I'm trying to do some simple DOM manipulation like removing elements and adding buttons to a site. I got it working but the problem is that for some reason the DOM manipulation doesn't happen all the time. I'd have to refresh the page and it will work sometimes. Not sure what's going on.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Twitch Filter",
  "version": "1",
  "description": "Filters out streamers and games for www.twitch.tv",
  "background": {"page": "background.html"},
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Twitch Filter",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "background.js"],
    "css": ["customStyles.css"],
    "matches": [ "http://www.twitch.tv/directory/all", "https://www.twitch.tv/directory/all", "https://www.twitch.tv/directory/random", "http://www.twitch.tv/directory/random"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

background.js

```
var blockedUsers= ['/test'];
var blockedTypes = ['test'];

$(document).ready(function() {

  console.log("LOADED");
  blockGames(blockedTypes);
  blockStreamers(blockedUsers);
  addBlockUserButtons();

  MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
      // fired when a mutation occurs
      blockGames(blockedTypes);
      blockStreamers(blockedUsers);
      addBlockUserButtons();
      // ...
  });

  // define what element should be observed by the observer
  // and what types of mutations trigger the callback
  var target = document;
  var config = {subtree: true, attributes: false, childList: true, characterData:false};
  observer.observe(target, config);
});

function blockStreamers(blockedUsers) {
  var streamUserNames = document.querySelectorAll('a.cap');
  for(i = 0; i < streamUserNames.length;i++)
  {
      var item = streamUserNames[i];
      var blockedBoolean = $.inArray(item.getAttribute('href'), blockedUsers);
      if (blockedBoolean != -1) {
        $(item).closest('div[class^="stream item"]').remove();
      }
  }
};

function blockGames(blockedTypes) {
  var streamBoxArts = document.querySelectorAll('a.boxart');
  for(i=0; i < streamBoxArts.length;i++)
  {
    var item = streamBoxArts[i];
    var blockedBoolean = $.inArray(item.getAttribute('title'), blockedTypes);
    if (blockedBoolean != -1) {
      $(item).closest('div[class^="stream item"]').remove();
    }
  }
};

function addBlockUserButtons() {
  var usersList = $('p.info').children('a');
  for(i = 0; i < usersList.length;i++) {
    var user = usersList[i];
    var streameUserName = user.getAttribute('href').replace('/profile', '');
    var blockIdName = 'blockuser_link_' + streameUserName.replace('/','');
    var newNode = document.createElement('a');
    newNode.setAttribute('href', '#');
    newNode.setAttribute('id', blockIdName);
    $(newNode).text('BLOCK');
    user.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, user.nextSibling);
    document.getElementById(blockIdName).addEventListener('click', createBlockUserFunc(streameUserName));
  }
};

function createBlockUserFunc(i) {
    return function() {
      blockUser(i);
    };
}

function blockUser(streamer){
  blockedUsers.push(streamer);
  blockStreamers(blockedUsers);
};
```

Comment: What's your code? It might be that the extension executes the code immediatly but the website it isn't fully loaded. What if you run your code within a `timeout`?

Comment: i've edited the original post with the background.js

Comment: Did you put the `background.js` at the bottom of your html file? Could you attach the html file?

Comment: no my html file is empty. I was going to put something else on there later. does it have to be included in the background.html file? doesn't the manifest content script ensure its injected ?

Comment: Your match pattern is invalid (it has to have a path). I understand you're just adding a dummy one to the question, but it might be that you have an error there, and it also depends on how the website in question navigates. Can you add your real match pattern for the content script?

Comment: @Xan I've added the actual manifest.json the pattern match is fine on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if it's really an answer, but the problem seems to only happen on my macbooks Yosemite chrome browser. I've tested this on a friends linux laptop and my girlfriends Windows 7 Desktop and my work laptop and can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there's something unusual about the site in question that causes the DOM to not become ready for an unusual length of time, and your content scripts are not running because you've set them to run at document_end. You might try seeing if switching to document_idle makes any difference. Also, you might try a simple test like just having your content script do something like console.log('hello world') and verifying that the script is actually running on the page; if that always works then you can progressively add more code to the hello world script from your full actual code, and eventually you should find a point at which it starts breaking.

Comment: I've tried adding the console.log before and verified the script doesn't actually load on the occasions that it doesn't load. I've tried to switch the full thing to hello world and it loads fine every time. Though I think I found the solution to the problem (kind of not really). I've had multiple friends test out my code for me and they said they don't encounter the issue. So I proceeded to test it on my work laptop and my girlfriends desktop and I can't reproduce the problem. So it seems to have something to do with my macbooks chrome browser.